# Add a pin not counted in bounding box

Tags: tikz-pgf, bounding-box, clip

I would like to use Tikz to annotate some terms in equations. I have attempted the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2]{\tikz[anchor=base, baseline, #1]{\node[rectangle, rounded corners, #1] {#2};}}
\[
a + b + c
\]
\[
\tikzbox{pin=-70:{first term}}{$a$} + b + c
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

As you can see, the text in the pin changes the bounding box and introduces spacing around the term $a$. Is it possible to alter this example so that the pin "does not count" and the space around $a$ is the same as in the first equation?

Comment: The tag "beamer" is wrong, this here is tikz-pgf question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `overlay` tikz option makes the tikz code not take up space:

```
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2]{%
   \tikz[overlay,anchor=base, baseline, #1]{% added overlay
      \node[rectangle, rounded corners, #1] {#2};
   }%
}
```

This will however also exclude the node's contents from the bounding box.
To exclude only the pin you can set the bb manually to just the size of the node:

```
\tikz[anchor=base, baseline, #1]{
    \node[rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, #1] (mynode) {#2};
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path [use as bounding box] (mynode.north west) -- (mynode.south east);
  }%
}
```

Here I also set the sep to zero to make the node's size tight around the content.
For that reason you may need to shorten the pin's edge to get a better result.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2]{%
  \tikz[anchor=base, baseline, #1]{
    \node[rectangle, rounded corners, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt, #1] (mynode) {#2};
    \pgfresetboundingbox
    \path [use as bounding box] (mynode.north west) -- (mynode.south east);
  }%
}
\[
a + b + c
\]
\[
\tikzbox{pin={[pin edge={shorten <=1mm}]-70:{first term}}}{$a$} + b + c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Note that the [`tikzmark`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf) package offers flexible support for exactly this kind of annotations and may be a more solid solution than a custom macro.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the bounding box. You should also set the inner sep to zero:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2]{\tikz[anchor=base, baseline, #1]
      {\node[rectangle, rounded corners, #1,name=mynode,inner sep=0pt] {#2};
       \pgfresetboundingbox
       \path[use as bounding box] (mynode.south west) rectangle (mynode.north east)}}
\[
a + b + c
\]
\[
\tikzbox{pin=-70:{first term}}{$a$} + b + c
\]
blblblb this is the next line blblb
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just a few seconds faster than me ;)

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution with `\rlap`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzbox}[2]{\tikz[anchor=base, baseline, #1]{\node[rectangle, rounded corners, #1] {#2};}}

 \pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[
a + b + c
\]
\[
\rlap{\tikzbox{pin=-70:{\scriptsize first term}}{}}a + b + c
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]